# JS: Error in IE, compatible in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm having IE give me this error for a small function I wrote:

> Message: Object expected Line: 13
>   Char: 52 Code: 0

Here is my code (please excuse the formatting):

```
function SectionTwo()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        if( xmlhttp.status==200 ) {
            if( xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf( "404 Error" ) >= 0 ) { } 
            else {
                var idtagsArray = ["KT501-1_8","KT502-15_30","KT503-15_37","KT504-10_30","KT505-30_80","KT506-30_90","KT507-20_50","KT510-15_1440","KT512-0_1_2_3_4","KT513-30_80","KT514-0_1","KT520-0_1","KT525-0_1_2","KT526-0_1","KT527-0_9999","KT529-0_9999","KT531-0_9999","KT533-0_9999","KT535-0_250","KT536-0_9999","KT538-0_9999","KT548-0_1","KT549-0_1","KT550-102_120", "KT551-80_98","KT552-15_37","KT553-0_30","KT554-50_90","KT555-20_50","KT565-0_10","KT566-0_20","KT567-0_30","KT568-0_50","KT569-1_10","KT570-1_10","KT571-2_10","KT572-2_10","KT573-1_20","KT574-1_30"];
                for(var tag = 0; tag < idtagsArray.length; tag++) {
                    UpdateImage( idtagsArray[tag], xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last line is line 13. I also have another function called `SectionOne` which is identical to the above except that it calls `UpdatePoint` instead of `UpdateImage`, and that one does not error out.

Chrome and Firefox do not show any JS errors and work as intended. Here is the `UpdateImage` function:

```
function UpdateImage( usediv, data )
{
    if( data == null || data.length <= 0 ) {
        update_value.innerText = 0;
        return
    }

    // [A5:1][A6:1][A7:1][A8:1]
    var start       = data.indexOf( "[" + usediv + ":" ) + 2 + usediv.length ;
    var end         = data.indexOf( "]", start );
    var data_value  = data.slice( start , end ) ;

    if( data_value > 0 )
    {
        document.getElementById(usediv).style.display = "";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(usediv).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the lack of a semi-colon on the `return` in `UpdateImage`?

*Edit*:

In that case you just have some obscure syntax oddity that IE is confused about (happens all the time :)).

Start removing code. Get rid of all those nested if's (probably should be refactored anyway). Don't do a `for` loop, just call `UpdateImage( idtagsArray[0], xmlhttp.responseText )`. Make your `idtagsArray` only 1 element long. Etc.

Comment: It's not that, although I missed it thanks. The error still occurs when I make UpdateImage a stub function with no code.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the missing semicolon after `return` in your function `UpdateImage`?